# GUI started emacs has different env vars than terminal started one

Tags: spacemacs, bash, ubuntu

I wrote `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` both in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

However, if I started emacs in terminal using `emacs`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is shown in `getenv`.
If I started it using GUI, there is no such variable.

I am on ubuntu 20.04. How could I make GUI started emacs have same env vars as terminal started one?

Comment: What's the question? "Any ideas?" isn't a specific question.

Comment: @Drew Tks for your comment. I edited accordingly:P

Comment: This is not really an emacs question: it really depends on the GUI, and how it is started. I would suggest you ask the question on the Unix & Linux SE site - and specify which GUI you are using.

Comment: Your GUI isn't a shell, so there's no reason why it would read your bash init scripts.  You either need to figure out how to configure the environment for your GUI, or else how to change the way the GUI launches Emacs so that it adds things to the environment.  Alternatively, some people use https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell to make Emacs itself process shell init files.

Comment: In general, Emacs uses a variable called `process-environment` and that can be configured globally, and it can be configured on a buffer-local basis, and it can also be configured to relate only to a specific subprocess.  I personally configure it on a buffer-local basis, and also as to specific subprocesses that are launched.  I almost never rely upon a global setting once Emacs launches, but that is just my personal preference.  To inspect the `process-environment`, type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable` ....  If you need additional help modifying that variable, perhaps edit your question.

Comment: You can set the desired environment in your init  file. eg (unless(getenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH") (setenv "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "/mon/chemin/vers/library"))

Comment: The environnment vars are inherited from the program that launched Emacs (that's true for *all* programs), so what you're seeing is that your DE (desktop environment) has a different set of env-vars than your shell (because you set env vars in your shell's startup script).  Nothing Emacs can do about it.